# Can you build and submit UWP apps that are compatible with Windows Phone 8.1, when using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-10

In Windows 8.1, and Visual Studio 2013, you could build a UWP app, that would work with both Windows Phone 8.1, and Windows 10.

In Windows 10, and Visual Studio 2015, can you build a UWP app, that would work with both Windows Phone 8.1, and Windows 10 ?

While this is not a programming question, it is more likely that the persons who know the answer to this question will be on this site, rather than on superuser.

EDIT: I made a mistake - what I meant is whether you can build an app for Windows 8.1 & windows phone 8.1, but which also works on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, I think you are confusing ***universal windows apps*** which were targeted to windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1 but will also run on windows 10 with ***universal windows platform(UWP)*** apps which are targeted to windows 10 devices (and [cannot be developed on vs2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5af514fe-a452-4209-89f4-0f2fcb131b8f/uwpis-it-supported-to-develop-uwp-apps-using-visual-studio-2013?forum=wpdevelop))

Quote from the link.

> No, it is not possible to develop the UWP apps using the Visual Studio 2013, we need to use the Visual Studio 2015. But we can develop the Univsersal 8.1 app using the Visual Studio 2013 and port it to the UWP app on the Visual Studio 2015.

Now to answer your question. 
It is not possible to develop a UWP app that will run both on Windows phone 8.1 and Windows 10 (neither in vs2013 or in vs2015) because a UWP app does not run on windows phone 8.1.

From my understanding however, what you are trying to develop is an app that will run on windows phone 8.1 and on windows 10.

Depending on your needs you have the following options.

- **The old way**: Just develop a universal windows app (not a UWP) that will run on windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1. This app will run on windows 10 and windows 10 mobile just fine, but you will not be able to leverage any of the UWP exclusive apis of course.
- **The old way (with a modern touch)** : Start with the old way. Set up a solution with a [shared project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802607.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and a windows phone 8.1 head. Then add a UWP head. In the shared project you can use [compiler directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) to use UWP code without breaking the windows phone 8.1 app and vice versa. This of course can be done in VS 2015 just make sure to include the windows 8.1 relevant tools when you install it.

Comment: You are right - I meant the apps which are targeted to windows 8.1, but will also run on windows 10. So can I build a "Universal windows app" with VS 2015 ? Or can I atleast install 2013 on windows 10, and build the same app ?

Comment: Yes you can do both. When you install vs2015 make sure to include the windows 8.1 tools or if you have it installed already you can go to add/remove programs find it and then select repair or modify. You can also find the tools [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk)